# How to preview a file in a pop up window in the community page LWC Salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components, community

I'm stuck to that issues and don't know how to fix that, so As I know standard library such as 'NavigationMixin' for file preview won't correctly work in the community page, so that code won't work

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
     type: 'standard__namedPage',
     attributes: {
        pageName: 'filePreview'
     },
     state : {
        selectedRecordId: docId
     }
 })
```

Anyway i found a solution, its to create corresponding record in 'ContentDistribution' object and DistributionPublicUrl field on contentDistribution gets populated automatically. then i can use it something like that:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__webPage',
    attributes: {
        url: DistributionPublicUrl
    }
});
```

And it works perfect, but opens the file in the new browser window, not in popup window. Does anyone knows how to fix that? Thanks in advance. By the way i use lwc